# Problem with simplifying trigonometric summations

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

My problem arises when I evaluate

```
Q[s_, n_] = 1 - Sum[Cos[-2 π (s - 1)((k - 1)/n)]/n, {k, 1, n}]
F[s_, n_] = FullSimplify[Sum[Q[s, n], {j, 1, n}], {s, n} ∈ Integers]

λ = 3;
Table[{1 - Sum[Cos[-2 π (s - 1)*((k - 1)/λ)]/λ, {k, 1, λ}]}, {s, 1, 2^λ}][[All,1]]
Table[{Q[s, λ]}, {s, 1, 2^λ}][[All, 1]]
Table[{F[s, λ]}, {s, 1, 2^λ}][[All, 1]]
Clear[λ]
```

Here is a screenshot of the above code and the outputs

[image: Image of Code]

Output 29 and 30 are from the first two code boxes, while output 32-34 are from the three different generated tables.

I got this formula from a Wikipedia article on periodic sequences. Only output 32 is showing a result that agrees with the article. Why this is happening and how can I stop it from happening.

Comment: Both `F` and `Q` expect a positive integer as their second argument, but `Test` is undefined.  The question must be missing something.

Comment: Sorry, I was using Test instead of the lambda symbol while I was struggling with the problem. They are the same though

Comment: `Q[s_, n_] = 
   FullSimplify[1 - Sum[Cos[-2*Pi*(s - 1)*
              ((k - 1)/n)]/n, {k, 1, n}], 
     Element[{s, n}, Integers]]` evaluates to `1` and eliminates the indeterminate expression.

Comment: @BobHanlon  But, with `s == 1` and  `n == 3`,  `1 - Sum[Cos[-2 Pi*(1 - 1) (k - 1)/3]/3, {k, 3}]` yields `0`.  Evidently, `FullSimplify` is returning a generic result.

Comment: Hint for improving your code: `Table[Q[s, λ], {s, 1, 2^λ}]` gives the same result as `Table[{Q[s, λ]}, {s, 1, 2^λ}][[All, 1]]`, but with less computation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem illustrates the difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed`.  `Q` employs `Set` and so evaluates immediately.

```
Q[s_, n_] = 1 - Sum[Cos[-2 Pi*(s - 1) (k - 1)/n]/n, {k, n}]
(* 1 - (Cos[(π (2 + n - 2 s))/(2 n)] Csc[(π (-1 + s))/n] - 
       Cos[(-2 π + 3 n π + 2 π s - 4 n π s)/(2 n)] Csc[(π (-1 + s))/n])/(2 n) *)
```

The `Csc[(π (-1 + s))/n]` factor gives rise to the error messages when `(-1 + s))/n` is an integer.  But, with `SetDelayed`,

```
R[s_, n_] := 1 - Sum[Cos[-2 Pi*(s - 1) (k - 1)/n]/n, {k, n}]
```

is evaluated only when called.

```
λ = 3;
Table[{R[s, λ]}, {s, 1, 2^λ}][[All, 1]]
(* {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1} *)
```